# jdeps failing on sprinboot project

Tags: java, jdeps

i have springboot web application, i am trying to run jdeps (using java11) on this project, it is failing with error.

jdeps command: `jdeps --print-module-deps --multi-release 9 -cp ./*.jar .`

exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found, required by java.ws.rs
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:877)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:191)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:140)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:411)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:245)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration.<init>(JdepsConfiguration.java:117)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration$Builder.build(JdepsConfiguration.java:563)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.buildConfig(JdepsTask.java:589)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:543)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:519)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

Answer (score 0):

The module java.xml.bind was removed in JDK11, and that multi-release jar was compiled against JDK9 and requires it.